# how can I remove HTML comment-tag from XML data

Tags: php, html, json, xml

Code:

```
$string = htmlspecialchars($vakanz["stellenbeschrieb"]);
echo $string;
```

Output:

```
<!-- Haushalthilfe, stundenweise<br /> <br /> Fensterreinigungen und Fr&uuml;hjahrsputz<br /> -->
```

The Data comes from a web-application, where I get the content with following code:

```
function getVakanzDetail() 
{
    $vakanzId = $_GET['nummer'];
    $apiUrl = getApiUrl('vakanzDetail');
    $rawXml = file_get_contents($apiUrl . $vakanzId);
    $xmlElement = simplexml_load_string($rawXml, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA);
    $json = json_encode($xmlElement);
    $data = json_decode($json, true);

    $vakanz = $data['vakanz'];

    foreach ($vakanz as $key => $value) {
        if ($value === []) {
            $vakanz[$key] = '';
        }
    }

    return $vakanz;
}
```

When I look directly at the xml, I can see that the field  from which I get this output has exactly this information inside.

```
<stellenbeschrieb>
    <!-- Haushalthilfe, stundenweise<br /> <br /> Fensterreinigungen und Fr&uuml;hjahrsputz<br /> -->
</stellenbeschrieb>
```

My question is: How can I modify this to get an Output like this, without the HTML tags:
Haushalthilfe, stundenweise
Fensterreinigungen und Frühjahrsputz

Comment: so you also want to remove the break tags aswell?

Comment: the break tags can stay there if they would break. But at the moment they are in the output as text.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the below logic to the xml string that you get from external source.

```js
var commenttag = "<!-- Haushalthilfe, stundenweise<br /> <br /> Fensterreinigungen und Fr&uuml;hjahrsputz<br /> -->";

var newtext = commenttag.replace(/<!--/g,"").replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/g,"").replace(/-->/g,"");

console.log(newtext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
function remove($str){
    $str = str_replace("<!--", "",$str);
    $str = str_replace("-->", "",$str);
    return $str;
}
$str = "<!-- Haushalthilfe, stundenweise<br /> <br /> Fensterreinigungen und Fr&uuml;hjahrsputz<br /> -->";
echo strip_tags(remove($str));
```

This simple function `remove()` will remove the start and end comment.

And [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) remove all html tags from the string.

Try this in your code after you add the `remove()` function.

`echo strip_tags(remove($vakanz["stellenbeschrieb"]));`

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML is an abstraction on top of DOM, but in some cases you need to go a level lower. In DOM anything is a node, elements, whitespaces and - important in this case - comments. So you can use Xpath to fetch the comment nodes:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//stellenbeschrieb/comment()') as $comment) {
  var_dump($comment->textContent);
}
```

Output:

```
string(90) " Haushalthilfe, stundenweise<br /> <br /> Fensterreinigungen und Fr&uuml;hjahrsputz<br /> "
```

The text inside the comment is an HTML fragment. If you load that into a second DOM, it will add `html` and `body` tags by default, but that makes it easy to fetch just the text - without tags and with decoded html entities:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//stellenbeschrieb/comment()') as $comment) {

  $htmlDocument = new DOMDocument();
  $htmlDocument->loadHtml($comment->textContent);
  $htmlXpath = new DOMXpath($htmlDocument);

  var_dump($htmlXpath->evaluate('string(//body)')); 
}
```

Output:

```
string(65) "Haushalthilfe, stundenweise Fensterreinigungen und Frühjahrsputz"
```